# Menu missing, categories not accessible and home page shows error after moving to a new server

Tags: magento2

I moved a Magento 2.3 shop to a new server. Deployment and reindex as well as cleaning cache works just fine. The frontend however shows `There was no Home CMS page configured or found.` on the home page (it is configured correctly) and category urls do not work any longer, also the menu is missing (which might be related to the categories not working). All categories are visible in admin.

I think its all the same reason, but what could it be?

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked System -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Pages